# Nginx proxy Apache2 php ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

I deployed an application in docker, which is a php application with apache2.
There is an nginx in docker, used to proxy to applications.
[www.myhost.com](http://www.myhost.com) -> nginx(docker) -> my application(docker)

If I request my application through host:port, it runs successfully.
When I request my application through domain name, it gets ERR_CONNECTION_RESET randomly.

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhost.com;
    client_max_body_size 5120m;
    location / {
        #client_max_body_size 1024M;
        #proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_request_buffering off;
        #proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.17.19:8080/;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just looking at a [couple of other answers](https://serverfault.com/a/793607) out there, can you try disabling compression with nginx?

Comment: @johnson which docker images do you use?  `192.168.17.19` is your bridge address? can you add more details like `docker run`, `docker-compose` or `Dockerfile` to simulate problem?

Comment: Look for this article on freeCodeCamp: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-nginx-letsencrypt-easy-secure-reverse-proxy-40165ba3aee2/

Comment: try to add `proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;` into location section

Comment: Could you try to `curl -I http://192.168.17.19:8080/` inside your nginx container. I suspect it can't reach your application.

Comment: @sykez The netwok is ok, my problem is connection reset randomly, which is confusing.

Comment: @AdamP. Thanks very much, I'll try is later.

Comment: @ismaildurmaz I'll create s small demo later.

Answer (score 0):

Use this config for Nginx server to use Nginx as a reverseproxy

```
upstream myhost {
    server <docker-container-hostname/IP-address>:<port>
}

server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   myhost.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://myhost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works where the OP's version doesn't? At a quick glance, it looks identical except that you are using an `upstream` which allows you to specify multiple hosts, and you are omitting `proxy_` directives. If this offers more than that it would help the OP and future readers to understand the differences.

Comment: This is basically the same thing with upstream and no headers.

Comment: My problem is not nginx not working, it works fine at most requests, but failed randomly with connection reset.